# client side validation not working on HTML editor in C# MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Actually i am working in c# MVC4 architecture, i am also using newget, i am installing tinymce package in my application and in Company model property name  AboutCompany and Company profile have the REQUIRED ANNOTATION but it is not working on client side.

Please see the following code
this is my MODEL.

```
public class BusinessProfile
{
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter About Company")]
    [Display(Name = "About Company : ")]
    [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
    public string txtAboutCompany { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Company Name")]
    [Display(Name = "Company Name : ")]
    public string companyname{get;set;}

}
```

This is my View means HTML code

```
 <div>
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.txtBusinesstitle, new { @class = "required" })
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.txtBusinesstitle)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.txtBusinesstitle)
</div>
```

When i am submitting this form the validation message does not show the particular message,
i am also load the jquery bundles and also providing the scripting but not working proparly

```
 @section Scripts {
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn on client validation and unobtrusive validation from webconfig file.

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Also check what scripts you are referencing **~/bundles/jqueryval** with this bundle.

And check your browser what js errors it throws.

Comment: No Dear, No any js error throws and i check my web.xml file both are  already true

Comment: this problem is occurs only on html editor, it is working properly in normal text box or textarea....

Comment: @jegs Sorry I thought that you could not validate simple textboxes too. And problem is that validation doesn't work on tinyMCE editor...

Comment: Check this post too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628990/tinymce-client-validation-problem

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to create a custom jquery validator. The way the **Required** attribute works is that it relies on the jquery validation plugin.

If look at the html source that gets generated you'll see that the inputs that were generated by the helpers(e.g. Html.EditorFor) for the properties annotated with Required will have a class="required" or just an attribute required on them.

jquery validation picks up on them though jquery selectors (this is the unobtrusive part)

I'll bet that the model property for tinymce package is not being rendered with *EditorFor* or equivalent helper. You can still use jquery validation thought. If it is just a normal input (I'm not too familiar with tinymce), just make sure that it either has class="required" or just a required attribute (both will work).

If it is not a normal input, you can always create your own jquery validator. Here's a very simple example:

```
$.validator.addMethod("custom", function(value){
    return value != "1";        
}, "default custom error message");
```

The way you'd use it is just place class="custom" or just do this
`<input name="x" custom/>`

Here's a [fiddle that shows the above example working](http://jsfiddle.net/ruidfigueiredo/2QWPw/) and a more elaborate one that shows how you can [control highlights and other nice features of jquery validation](http://jsfiddle.net/ruidfigueiredo/dv97a/).

[**Easy to follow jquery validation tutorial**](http://www.camcloud.com/blog/jquery-form-validation-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the values inside a jQuery form.

MVC validation requires that the validated fields are inside a MVC form created by using any of the `Html.BeginForm()` overloads, because it requires a `FormContext` [See this Q&A from more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481552/asp-net-mvc-unobtrusive-validation-why-form-context-is-needed).

You need also to make sure that you have client side validation enabled, in `web.config`:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```